# Android: How to pass Bitmap Images to ArrayList<Bitmap> and retrieve it

Tags: java, android, arraylist, bitmap

"Base64Parts" is a string that has been split to equal parts, and I am trying to generate a QR code for each string and place it in a arraylist so that i can retrieve it and generate a GIF. Am I adding the bitmap images to the arraylist in the correct way? Because i can only retrieve "`bmp_images.get(0)`". Not others `(eg-bmp_images.get(1))`. My code is given below.

```
//Declaring QR code generator
QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();

//Declaring Array
ArrayList<Bitmap> bmp_images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPartsSplit; i++){

    try {
        Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel> hintMap = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, ErrorCorrectionLevel>();
        hintMap.put(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.L);
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(Base64Parts.get(i), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512, hintMap);
        int width = bitMatrix.getWidth();
        int height = bitMatrix.getHeight();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, bitMatrix.get(x, y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
            }
        }

        bmp_images.add(i,bmp); //the code added for arraylist of images

        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_holder)).setImageBitmap(bmp_images.get(0)); //use different values

    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I've tried it with the
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_holder)).setImageBitmap(bmp_images.get(0));
outside the for loop. Then i don't get any output for index '0' as well

Comment: if you have base 64 then directly save them as string why converting to bitmap?

Comment: @VivekMishra my main purpose is to generate multiple QR code bitmap images. So, arraylists seem to be the only way to store it

Comment: but base64 is string itself so why you are first converting them to bitmap and then saving it. Convert your saved string to bitmap when you need it

Comment: I am trying to save it so that i can use those images again to create a GIF or a video.

Answer (score 0):

```
((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_holder)).setImageBitmap(bmp_images.get(0));
```

paste this line outside **for** loop. Once all iteration done, set the needed index to get that particular value.

Comment: I tried that as well. Then i don't get any images at all. Even the index '0' doesn't work